# Oracle APEX - customizing bar chart

Tags: oracle-apex

Is it possible to make a bar chart a double y-axis?

I have a bar chart with 4 bars, generated by the query, returning 4 rows.

Is there a way for me to make each bar a different color and on the right-hand side, instead of series name, specify colors along with labels for each bar?

Answer (score 5):

Click on one of the chart series and look for the 'Assign to Y-Axis' attribute

[image]

Not how this is next to a 'Color' attribute. You can source this colour [from your SQL](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4264844), substituting your value using the using &COLUMN_ALIAS. syntax.

An example from the sample charts application in the linked form post shows how colour can be row based (with column alias adjusted to match my screenshot)

```
select a.product_name, 
       b.quantity, 
       b.customer,
       -- This is the column you're looking for
       case when b.quantity > 50 then 'gold'
            when b.quantity <= 30 then 'red' 
         when b.quantity > 30 then 'green'
         else 'blue'
       end as colour
from eba_demo_chart_products a, eba_demo_chart_orders b
where a.product_id = b.product_id
and customer = 'Store A'
```

Comment: but won't this change the color for all 4 bars? I need all 4 to be different colors

Comment: yes, colour can be row based - added example in answer.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to show labels along with colors on the right-hand side of the graph, in place of the series name? like [color]- label<br/>[color2]-label2

Comment: Name your series after the colours? (And enable the legend)

Comment: Important nuance:  &COLUMN_ALIAS.  <-- this variable only works if it is ALL CAPS

Comment: Yes, one of the few areas where Oracle APEX is sensitive about case - the &THING. syntax.